# Difficulties with my python tic-tac-toe

Tags: python, function, for-loop, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe

I am following Charles Dierbach's book, Introduction to Computer Science using Python.

I am on chapter 5. I am trying to do this exercise on tic-tac-toe automate play.

I am having difficulties creating a function for the pc to select an empty box ([]).

Here is my code

```
import re
import random
def template():
    mylst = list()
    for i in range(0, 3):
        my_temp = []
        for j in range(0, 3):
            my_temp.append([])
        mylst.append(my_temp)
    return mylst
def template_2(alst):
    print()
    al = ("A", "B", "C")
    for a in al:
        if a == "A":
            print (format(a, ">6"), end="")
        if a == "B":
            print (format(a, ">5"), end="")
        if a == "C":
            print (format(a, ">5"), end="")

    print()
    for j in range(len(alst)):
        print(str(j + 1), format( " ", ">1"), end="")
        print(alst[j])
        print()

def print_template(alst):
    print()
    al = ("A", "B", "C")
    for a in al:
        if a == "A":
            print (format(a, ">6"), end="")
        if a == "B":
            print (format(a, ">4"), end="")
        if a == "C":
            print (format(a, ">3"), end="")

    print()
    for j in range(len(alst)):
        print(str(j + 1), format( " ", ">1"), end="")
        print(alst[j])
        print()

def first_player(lst):
    print()
    print ("Your symbol is 'X'. ")
    alpha = ("A", "B", "C")
    #check it was entered correctly
    check = True
    temp_lst1 = []
    while check:
        correct_entry = False
        while not correct_entry:
            coord = input("Please enter your coordinates ")
            player_regex = re.compile(r'(\w)(\d)')
            aSearch = player_regex.search(coord)
            if aSearch == None:
                correct_entry = False
            if aSearch.group(1) != "A" or aSearch.group(1) != "B" or aSearch.group(1) != "C" or aSearch.group(2) != 1 or aSearch.group(2) == 2 or aSearch.group(3) != 3:
                correct_entry = False
            if aSearch.group(1) == "A" or aSearch.group(1) == "B" or aSearch.group(1) == "C" or aSearch.group(2) == 1 or aSearch.group(2) == 2 or aSearch.group(3) == 3:
                correct_entry = True
            else:
                correct_entry = True
        blank = False
        while not blank:
            if lst[(int(coord[-1])) - 1][alpha.index(coord[0])] == []:
                lst[(int(coord[-1])) - 1][alpha.index(coord[0])] = "X"
                temp_lst1.append((int(coord[-1])-1))
                temp_lst1.append((alpha.index(coord[0])))
                blank = True
            else:
                blank = True
                correct_entry = False
        if blank == True and correct_entry == True:
            check = False
    return True









def pc_player(lst):
    print()
    print ("PC symbol is 'O'. ")
    alpha = ("A", "B", "C")
    num_list = (0, 1, 2)

    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        for j in range(0, len(lst[i])):
            if lst[i][j] ==[]:
                lst[i][j] = "O"
            break
        break

    return True








def check_1st_player(lst):
    if lst[0][0] == "X" and lst[0][1] == "X" and lst[0][2] == "X":
        return True
    elif lst[1][0] == "X" and lst[1][1] == "X" and lst[1][2] == "X":
        return True
    elif lst[2][0] == "X" and lst[2][1] == "X" and lst[2][2] == "X":
        return True
    elif lst[0][0] == "X" and lst[1][0] == "X" and lst[2][0] == "X":
        return True
    elif lst[0][1] == "X" and lst[1][1] == "X" and lst[2][1] == "X":
        return True
    elif lst[0][2] == "X" and lst[1][2] == "X" and lst[2][2] == "X":
        return True
    elif lst[0][0] == "X" and lst[1][1] == "X" and lst[2][2] == "X":
        return True
    elif lst[2][0] == "X" and lst[1][1] == "X" and lst[0][2] == "X":
        return True
    else:
        return False


def check_pc_player(lst):

    if lst[0][0] == "O" and lst[0][1] == "O" and lst[0][2] == "O":
        return True
    elif lst[1][0] == "O" and lst[1][1] == "O" and lst[1][2] == "O":
        return True
    elif lst[2][0] == "O" and lst[2][1] == "O" and lst[2][2] == "O":
        return True
    elif lst[0][0] == "O" and lst[1][0] == "O" and lst[2][0] == "O":
        return True
    elif lst[0][1] == "O" and lst[1][1] == "O" and lst[2][1] == "O":
        return True
    elif lst[0][2] == "O" and lst[1][2] == "O" and lst[2][2] == "O":
        return True
    elif lst[0][0] == "O" and lst[1][1] == "O" and lst[2][2] == "O":
        return True
    elif lst[2][0] == "O" and lst[1][1] == "O" and lst[0][2] == "O":
        return True
    else:
        return False

def play_game():
    ask = input("Do you want to play a two player game of Tic-Tac-Toe game? (y/n) ")

    if ask in yes_response:

        # contruct the template for tic-tac-toe
        print()
        print("How many rounds do you want to play? " )
        print("Please enter only odd integers" )
        print("Please enter your coordinates", end="")
        print(" using format A1 or B2")
        print("New Round")
        return True


def play_again():
    tell_me = input("Do you want you play a game ? (y/n)")
    if tell_me == "Y" or "y":
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_full(lst):
    count = 0
    for i in lst:
        for j in i:
            if j != []:
                count += 1
    if count == 9:
        return True
#
#-- main
print("Welcome to Awesome 2 Player Tic-Tac-Toe Game? ")
print()

answer = False
yes_response =("Y", "y")
no_response = ("N", "n")
while not answer:
    print("Enter an even integer to exit")
    ask = int(input("How many matches do you want to play? (odd integers only)? " ))
    game = play_game()
    structure = template()
    print_template(structure)
    if ask % 2 == 1:
        score_player1 = 0
        score_pc = 0
        count = 0
        while count < ask:
            pc_lst = []
            if count >= 1:
                structure = template()
                print_template(structure)

            while game:

                check_pc = True
                while check_pc:

                    pc_player(structure)
                    template_2(structure)
                    check_pc = False

                check_pc_winner = True
                while check_pc_winner:
                    game_pc = check_pc_player(structure)
                    check_pc_winner = False
                if game_pc == True:
                    print("Congratulations PC won")
                    score_pc += 1
                    game = False
                    break
                check_player1 = True
                while check_player1:
                    first_player(structure)
                    template_2(structure)
                    check_player1 = False
                check_first_winner = True
                while check_first_winner:
                    game_first = check_1st_player(structure)
                    check_first_winner = False
                if game_first == True:
                    print("Congratulations Player 1 won")
                    score_player1 += 1
                    game = False
                    break

                board_full = False
                while not board_full:
                    check_board = is_full(structure)
                    board_full = True
                if check_board == True:
                    print("This round was a tie.")
                    game = False

            print("Player 1 : ", score_player1, " PC : ", score_pc)
            count += 1
            game = True

    if score_player1 > score_pc:
        print("Player 1 won")
    elif score_player1 < score_pc:
        print("PC won")
    if play_again() == False:
           answer = True
    else:
        answer = False
```

The problem I have is at `def pc_player():`

I would like to know how to loop the list and sublists so that AI can select an empty box as its choice to place an "O"

My current for loop does not work. AI only selects the first box.

Comment: How do you guarantee that the list always contains an *empty box*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by finding all empty boxes:

```
empty= [(i,j) for i in range(len(lst)) for j in range(len(lst[i])) if lst[i][j]==[]]
```

Then choose a random one:

```
import random
chosen_i, chosen_j= random.choice(empty)
```

And finally put an `O` there:

```
lst[chosen_i][chosen_j]= 'O'
```

Comment: Thank you very much  for answering my question and giving me a solution that i will understand

Answer (score 1):

> My current for loop does not work. AI only selects the first box.

I suppose you refer to this part:

```
def pc_player(lst):
    print()
    print ("PC symbol is 'O'. ")
    alpha = ("A", "B", "C")
    num_list = (0, 1, 2)

    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        for j in range(0, len(lst[i])):
            if lst[i][j] ==[]:
                lst[i][j] = "O"
            break
        break

    return True
```

The `break` instructions together with the way you initialize the `for` loops will only attempt to set `lst[0][0]`. Other cells are not considered.

To make an evenly distributed random choice, it is essential to gather the possibilities first. For this, it is convenient to have all cells in a plain list first:

```
from itertools import chain
all_cells = list(chain.from_iterable(lst))
```

Then, you can filter out non-empty cells:

```
empty_cells = filter(lambda l: len(l) == 0, all_cells)
# empty_cells = filter(lambda l: not l, all_cells)
# empty_cells = [cell for cell in all_cells if not cell]
```

Based on this you can now trigger your random selection and symbol placement:

```
import random
cell_to_place = random.choice(empty_cells)
cell_to_place.append('O')
```

---

If you need the index of the cell being modified, you can do the following:

```
import itertools
indices = list(itertools.product(range(3), range(3)))
indexed_cells = zip(indices, map(lambda (i, j): lst[i][j], indices))
indexed_cells = filter(lambda (_, l): not l, indexed_cells) # filter non-empty
(i,j), cell_to_place = random.choice(indexed_cells)
# ...
```

---

These code samples *do not* take into account that there could be no empty cell left. Also, your code has some general design issues. For example:

- Why do you use lists as cell items in the first place? You could simply use `None`, `'X'` and `'O'` as the elements of the 2-dimensional list.
- `check_pc_player` and `check_1st_player` can be easily generalized by making the symbol to check for a parameter of the function.
- Why is this a while-loop?

  ```
      while check_first_winner:
          game_first = check_1st_player(structure)
          check_first_winner = False
  ```

Comment: I placed it in a while loop to check if player 1  won

Comment: Thank you for ur answer but i have not been  taught lambda or  most of the stuff you wrote  I am just a beginner

Comment: Yes, I see why you wanted to execute the code under a condition. But rethink the loop. Doesn't an if suffice? It's no big deal that you are beginning to learn. Lambdas are not difficult. Just keep an open mind and google the stuff you don't understand. I think the steps above are descriptive enough.